# Jquery ajax search loading animation does not stop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've wrote following code for searching via ajax. When key up fired, an ajax request is made after 500ms. But the searching animation doesn't stop (`hide()` method).

```
$('#mainsearch .searchinput').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.which !== 0) {
        var searchval = $(this).val().trim();
        if(aSearch[searchval]) {
            $('#mainsearch #sugbox #sugres').html(aSearch[searchval]);
        }else if(prevs !== searchval) {
            prevs = searchval;
            clearTimeout($.data(this, 'timer'));
            var wait = setTimeout(function() {search(searchval)}, 500);
            $(this).data('timer', wait);
        }
    }
});

function search(searchval) {
    console.log("searching for "+searchval)
    if(lastrequest && lastrequest.readystate != 4){ // abort past requests
        lastrequest.abort();
        lastrequest = null;
        delete lastrequest;
        $('#mainsearch #finding').hide();
    }

    if(searchval != "") { // make an ajax call

    lastrequest = $.ajax({
        url:"/ajaxsearch.php?key_word="+searchval,
        type: "GET",
        dataType:'json',
        cache:true,

        beforeSend:function() {
            $('#mainsearch #finding').delay(400).show(0);
        },

        complete: function(jqXHR, status){
            console.log('complete');
            $('#mainsearch #finding').hide();
        },

        success:function(result){
            $('#mainsearch #finding').hide();
            if(result.length > 0 ) {
                var outp = searchParse(result);
                $('#mainsearch #sugbox #sugres').html(outp);
                aSearch[searchval] = outp;
            } else 
            $('#mainsearch #sugbox #sugres').html('<li><a href="#"> Not Found </span></a></li>');
            $('#mainsearch #finding').hide();
        },

        error : function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                $('#mainsearch #finding').hide();
        }
    });
}
}
```

I get desired results in search with no error. but the `hide()` isn't hiding the animation. However, entering `$('#mainsearch #finding').hide();` hides the animation.

Note : Here `#mainsearch #finding` is a div which is animated by css3.

Comment: The `console.log('complete')` shows up though?

Comment: Yes. it shows up. Even when I run the `hide()` code in browser console, it hides the animation.

Comment: Is it possible that the delayed code in beforeSend fires after the ajax call completes? (tha AJAX call takes less than 400ms)

Comment: As a side note, some of your selectors are super redundant. If there can only be one element with a given `ID` you don't need to specify that it is inside some other element. Use `$('#finding')` instead of `$('#mainsearch #finding')`, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take away the delay i think ajax returns faster than delay...

```
     $('#mainsearch #finding').delay(400).show(0);
     $('#mainsearch #finding').show(0);
```

Comment: But I don't want to quickly show and hide the animation as it looks not fine.

Comment: then do it on document ready or after `if(searchval != "") {`  then you know it is after user typed something and before ajax call